# Exclude garbage collection time from method execution time

Tags: java, garbage-collection, execution, execution-time

I have a `Timer` class that measures a method execution time:

```
 public class Timer {
            private long startTime;

            public long start()  {
                    startTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
                    return startTime;
            }

            public long getElapsedTime()  {
                    return System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime;
            }
}
```

And I have a method that does some memory-heavy operations (like, copies into array millions of references to new different objects/millions of references to an existing object).

```
  public static void Test {
        private static Timer timer=new Timer();
        private static String s0="STRING";
        private static long size=5000_000L;

        public static void main(String[] args)  {
              System.gc();
              foo();
              //bar();  //executed if foo() is commented
        }

        public static void foo()  {
              System.out.println("Foo starts: ");
              timer.start(); 
              for (int i=0; i<size; i++)  {
                   arrayList.add(s0);   
              }
              System.out.println("Foo ends: "+timer.getElapsedTime()+"ms");  
        }     

        public static void bar()  {
            //some code here
        }
}
```

When `foo()` is executed, a GC happens. It takes different time from run to run, for instance `[Times: user=0.80 sys=0.08, real=0.39 secs]` and `foo()` takes `1545 ms`. Then I have a `bar()` that does a similar thing and I want to find out if it's just as efficient. It takes `[Times: user=0.84 sys=0.06, real=0.31 secs]` and `1825 ms`.

What should I do to find out which method is effective, if I don't have enough RAM to avoid garbage collection during the run? Can I just subtract it like `1825-310` and `1545-390` and then compare the results?

**EDIT**: I run the methods separately: one is always commented out. `System.gc()` is used at the very beginning.

Comment: Jon Skeet [recommends](http://stackoverflow.com/a/504119/1553851) calling `System.gc()` between runs. You can also run with the `-verbose:gc` option so you tell what's actually happening.

Comment: @shmosel, I forgot to mention  - I use `System.gc()` as a first command in `main` and there is always only one method being executed.

Comment: @shmosel, As to `-verbose` it's already enabled. From what I can make of it, it collects garbage when the heap space is up.

Comment: Is the purpose benchmarking or monitoring?

Comment: @the8472, The puspose is benchmarking, finding out the best method and its success margin, relative to another method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java)

Comment: write a proper microbenchmark, look at its statistical output. *min* should represent performance without GC and *avg* performance with amortized GC which actually is more realistic.